# how to get latlng from LocationSettingsResponse method?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am Trying to make a map activity that i can choose my current location and make a marke on any location in the map,, i tried to use google documentation but i didn't understand how can i get latlng from this method any one have and idea about that !

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    // ...

    SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
            // location requests here.
            // ...
            

        }
    });
```

Comment: _"how to get latlng from LocationSettingsResponse method?"_ You don't. It only deals with location _settings_. As your comments in the code say _"The client can initialize location requests here."_ So, you still need to do the actual location request with `requestLocationUpdates()` and then wait for the `onLocationChanged()` callback. The operation may take a while, so even `getLastKnownLocation()` won't necessarily return an up-to-date location immediately and should be used with an understanding of that limitation. But you've got a nice answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem create a function like follows :

```
 public void centreMapOnLocation(Location location, String title){

    if (location != null) {
        LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(title));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 15));
    }
}
```

In onMapReady function add the following code :

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    mMap.clear();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                centreMapOnLocation(location, "Your Location");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0 , 0, locationListener);
            Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            centreMapOnLocation(lastKnownLocation, "Your Location");

        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    }
}
```

In the onMapLongClick :

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

String address = "";

try {

    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);

            if(listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0){

                if (listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null){
                    address += listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() + " ";
                }
                address += listAddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() + " ";


            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (address.equals("")){
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy");
            address += sdf.format(new Date());

        }
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(address));
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.luv.memorableplaces", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        try {

            ArrayList<String> lat = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> lng = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (LatLng coord : MainActivity.locations){

                lat.add(Double.toString(coord.latitude));
                lng.add(Double.toString(coord.longitude));

                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("latitudes", ObjectSerializer.serialize(lat)).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("longitudes", ObjectSerializer.serialize(lng)).apply();
            }

            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("places", ObjectSerializer.serialize(MainActivity.places)).apply();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This will also help you save the previous location. Try it out, it should work.

Comment: You wrote all this nonsense and didn't answer his question. How do you get location from LocationSettingsResponse? What is the use of LocationSettingsResponse if you can't get location from it.